# Docker run can't find the directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I wrote the Dockerfile like this

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
COPY requirements.txt /b/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /b/requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install subversion -y

#WORKDIR /a/
COPY . /a
WORKDIR /a
CMD find .

WORKDIR /b
COPY b_file.sh /b/b_file.sh
RUN chmod +x b_file.sh

VOLUME /log
VOLUME /a
VOLUME /c

CMD ["sh","/b/report_me.sh"]
```

And build ok, but when I start to docker run it can't find the directory

```
svn: E155007: '/a' is not a working copy
svn: E155007: '/a' is not a working copy
Skipped '.'
svn: E155007: None of the targets are working copies
svn: E155007: '/a' is not a working copy
```

how to solve this?? please let me know

Comment: can you share `report_me.sh` content? is it aware that you're within `/b`?

Comment: remove line : VOLUME /a from Dockerfile.

Comment: How did you run the container? Did you mount something to /a?

Comment: after creating requirements.txt, b_file.sh files using touch command the Dockerfile works for me, Successfully built 564f4daca027

Comment: thanks for all comments, The problem was the file that wasn't the right direction. directory b also need to in the same Dockerfile directory. and i don't know why copy command didn't copy.